How different is the electromagnetism taught to Engineers from the one taught to Physicists?
On average, of course. I have often seen the sentiment that engineering is somehow 'behind' physics in its understanding of electromagnetism.
This is not to mean that it is less right, rather that it has retained a lot of concepts and terminology from the earlier days of the science, from which it has mostly moved on by now.
For example, Physics tends to treat the 'magnetic induction density' $B$ as fundamental, and define it according to its force on moving charges. Engineering tends to treat the 'magnetic field strength" $H$ as fundamental, defining it by its force on a magnetic pole. This site along with Feynman's Lectures talk about this. The engineering version of electromagnetism is fairly close to the theories of Maxwell and other scientists from that time, when most of the knowledge of fields and charges was based on exclusively macroscopic experimental data. Back then they weren't even sure whether a moving charged body would create a magnetic field in the same way as a current in a conductor. It makes sense for engineering to have stayed around this point, since it doesn't really deal with things at a microscopic level.
In a somewhat stranger example, Einstein's The Electrodynamics of Moving Bodies (1905), although somewhat dated in its notation, treat the electromagnetic fields in a fairly modern way. Fields in space, how their derivatives relate to each other and not much more. On the other hand, Karapetoff's The Magnetic Circuit (1911), specifically a book geared toward engineers, talks of currents being induced by the circuit cutting through lines of magnetic induction, or the variation in total magnetic induction (or magnetic flux) through a circuit. This includes both induction by motion of the circuit and variation of the magnetic field. This is very similar to how Faraday and Maxwell spoke of electromagnetic induction.
Karapetoff even briefly discusses whether induction by variation of the magnetic field can also be considered to be caused by 'cutting' of the field lines, as the magnetic field lines shrink toward and expand away from the primary conductor, moving and cutting through the secondary conductor. A more modern treatment would just say there is an electric field associated with the changing magnetic field and call it a day, while Karapetoff doesn't really discuss the electric field induced. This is, again, similar to Maxwell's treatment in his treatise, where his equations define the electric field or 'electromotive intensity' as the sum of  the gradient of the electric potential, the time derivative of the magnetic potential, and the cross product of the medium's velocity with the magnetic induction.
I would like to know more about this divergence between the two fields, and whether it continues or is as pronounced nowadays. If there are any references talking about the subject, those would also be much appreciated.

Forty odd years ago as an electrical engineer, my sophomore E&M course used Jackson.

Engineering doesn't change until the changes have practical implications.  If treating "magnetic field strength" as fundamental gets you all the info you need more easily, they aren't going to change.

I think also that accredited or professional physicists, as a comparatively small minority, maintain certain ideological preferences about the interpretation of physics to which engineers are generally opposed.
